# Change the increment value for increasing brightness with Fn key in Windows 10

Tags: windows, brightness, regedit

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the increment value when I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> combination in order to change the screen brightness. A similar question would be for decreasing brightness with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> combination.

I have searched on the internet, but maybe I'm using bad keywords. I'm sure this option is stored somewhere in the Windows registry, otherwise how does Windows know to increase the screen brightness by 10 when I use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> special function?

My computer is an Ideapad L340-15IRH from Lenovo.

Comment: I suspect that this is not a Windows feature, but rather something provided by a hardware driver bundled with your laptop. What brand and model of laptop is it? Please [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: I said it's a Windows feature because I currently have a dualboot Windows / Ubuntu and the increment value for the screen brightness is different depending on the operating system.