# Change Windows 10 display brightness increment

Tags: windows-10, laptop, windows-registry, brightness

Is it possible to change the increment value of the brightness hotkey (in my case <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>F4</kbd>).

I've looked here, but there's only one [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1560303/change-the-increment-value-for-increasing-brightness-with-fn-key-in-windows-10) which was not answered. I'm very certain that this value can be changed somewhere, but I do not know where. In the action center, I can change the brightness smoothly using the slider.

All the other OS I am using (Pop OS, Manjaro) supports changing the brightness increment of the hotkey, so I am sure the hotkey isn't locked to a specific increment.

I am currently using Acer Swift 3 SF314-56G laptop.

Comment: From this thread [custom shortcut for screen brightness](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/custom-shortcut-for-screen-brightness/c0bbbea1-017c-4989-b037-cb586f349c4b), without function key it is not possible to create keyboard shortcut for brightness. Try following guidance to see if you can reassign hot keys for your keyboard. [How do I reassign hot keys for my keyboard?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-reassign-hot-keys-for-my-keyboard-703f897c-ad72-db5d-8e64-0928873d712f)